# white label pads in r plotly

Tags: r, plotly

There seems to be a bug with the placement of the white label paddings in plotly in r.

Take the following example code from [here](https://plot.ly/r/sankey-diagram/):

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
   type = "sankey",
   orientation = "h",
       node = list(
     label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
     color = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
     pad = 15,
     thickness = 20,
     line = list(
       color = "black",
       width = 0.5
     )
   ),
       link = list(
     source = c(0,1,0,2,3,3),
     target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
     value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2)
   )
 ) %>% 
 layout(
   title = "Basic Sankey Diagram",
   font = list(
     size = 10
   )
)
```

which produces this graph in R

[image: plotly example graph with wrong padding]

(compare with graph shown on the linked website where the white paddings are placed correctly)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14
```

Comment: It looks fine for me on windows... perhaps a mac thing?

Comment: Try to install the latest development version of plotly using `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`